# Specifying the location to save a file for Vuze

Tags: bittorrent, vuze

I was a long time user of Azureus and I recently installed Vuze after my upgrade from XP to Windows 7.  Azureus used to ask me where to save a file for each torrent I downloaded.  Vuze seems to put them all in one place.  Is there a way to change this behavior back to what Azureus did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now a plugin: [Save Path](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/plugin_details.php?plugin=azsavepath)

You can also make changes as mentioned in these [instructions](http://faq.vuze.com/?View=entry&EntryID=102)